# Cannot clear \r\n from Unity Input Field Text

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field

I'm dynamically adding and removing text from a multi-line input field that includes `\r\n` for my newlines.

I am unable to clear the `\r\n`.

I tried `inputfield = "";` but the `\r\n` still remain. So if I clear all the text content and add new content, the new content never starts at the top - it starts down however many lines `\r\n` where added since the app started.

Any ideas how to get around??

[image]

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

You mention you are doing `inputfield = "";` When in fact you have a Text component and not an InputField shown on the picture.

If you are using an **InputField**, it must be cleared on the InputField itself and not on the child **Text** game object. You do that like this:
`inputField.text = ""`

**As a last resort:** If nothing works, you can always remove your component using a Destroy call 
`Destroy(inputField);` and then add it back with `this.AddComponent<InputField>();`

Comment: yes sorry thats what meant.. Comments.text = CommentsKeeper + "\n";
Comments.text = ""; i like your second suggestion. thank you!